# How can I get the text in a textbox in customtkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am building a text editor but I can't save the file because I can't get the text within the textbox. Even thought in the entry widget I can use .get() to get the text.

I tried .get() but it displays an error that it isn't an option.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Customtkinter library is still under-development and it's getting updated consistently.

.get() function support was added couple of days ago, you can now use it. Make sure your customtkinter library is up-to-date. (pip3 install customtkinter --upgrade)

Example code:

```
from pytube import *
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter

def getText():
    print(textbox.get('1.0', END))

root = customtkinter.CTk()

textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(root)
button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, command=getText)
textbox.pack(pady=30, padx=20)
button.pack(pady=30, padx=20)

root.mainloop()
```